# split a time data CSV into different years and plot them in one graph

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a data sheet of 157619 rows. It contains hourly temperature measures in the time span of 2002 -  2019. I would like to plot a graph with a year on the time axis (x axis) and then draw all years on the same graph. For this task I was thinking to split the data into different DataFrames/Series containing each single year and then plot them into a diagram. The data looks like this:

```
Produkt_Code  SDO_ID   Zeitstempel  Wert  Qualitaet_Niveau  Qualitaet_Byte
0       TE100_MN002    4466  200201010000   4.5                 1            -999
1       TE100_MN002    4466  200201010100   4.5                 1            -999
2       TE100_MN002    4466  200201010200   4.5                 1            -999
3       TE100_MN002    4466  200201010300   4.5                 1            -999
4       TE100_MN002    4466  200201010400   4.5                 1            -999
...             ...     ...           ...   ...               ...             ...
157613  TE100_MN002    4466  201912311900   6.3                 0               1
157614  TE100_MN002    4466  201912312000   6.3                 0               1
157615  TE100_MN002    4466  201912312100   6.3                 0               1
157616  TE100_MN002    4466  201912312200   6.3                 0               1
157617  TE100_MN002    4466  201912312300   6.3                 0
```

So I only need the time as index and the temperatures, which can be found in the column Wert. I applied the read_csv to simpify the data:

```
data_100 = pd.read_csv(data_dir_100, parse_dates=True, usecols=["Wert", "Zeitstempel"], index_col="Zeitstempel")
```

The output looks like this:

```
                         Wert
Zeitstempel           
    2002-01-01 00:00:00   4.5
    2002-01-01 01:00:00   4.5
    2002-01-01 02:00:00   4.5
    2002-01-01 03:00:00   4.5
    2002-01-01 04:00:00   4.5
    ...                   ...
    2019-12-31 19:00:00   6.3
    2019-12-31 20:00:00   6.3
    2019-12-31 21:00:00   6.3
    2019-12-31 22:00:00   6.3
    2019-12-31 23:00:00   6.3
```

I am a beginner and don't know how to continue

Result to the first solution given:
[[image: Same result with changing "Temperatur" to "Wert]"[1]]

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you can adapt this snippet to solve your issue

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_dict = {
'Zeitstempel': ['2002-01-01 00:00:00','2002-01-01 01:00:00',
'2002-01-01 03:00:00','2002-01-01 04:00:00','2019-12-31 19:00:00',
'2019-12-31 20:00:00', '2019-12-31 21:00:00','2019-12-31 22:00:00',
'2019-12-31 23:00:00'],
'Temperatur':[6.7,6.6,6.7,6.7,10.7,10.7,10.7,10.7,10.7]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)

df[["Zeitstempel"]] = df[["Zeitstempel"]].apply(pd.to_datetime)
df.plot(kind='bar',x='Zeitstempel',y='Temperatur')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I'm not looking for the average temperature, just plotting the hourly data for each year. I tried to solve the problem with your code, but I get the error: `ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!`

Comment: if possible, could you please share the code snippet that's giving you that error?

Comment: I've made modifications to my answer. I'm curious how that plot turns out. If you can do share a screenshot of the graph :)

Comment: You can find the screenshot in the question :)

Comment: I think you're using the wrong column name for the y-axis. Your temperature column is actually labeled 'Wert' not 'Temperature'. Try using the correct column name and see if that solves your issue

Comment: Yeah, I changed the column name to 'Wert' in line 20. Could the problem be, because 'Zeitstempel' si not a column anymore but the index? You can see a similar output now.